# What is the difference between writing C#4 and C#11?

Tags: theory, chord-theory, jazz

I see C#11 in a lot of jazz music, but sometimes I'll see C#4 in jazz, and commonly in other types of music.  Is there any difference between the two, and if not, how do you decide which to write?

Comment: Are you referring to C# 11 or C #11? Is the sharp on C or on 11?

Answer (score 4):

It's actually a very big difference.

C♯11 is easily seen as an a extended chord that contains the notes C♯, E♯, G♯, B, (D♯), and F♯ though typically the 3rd (E♯) is omitted due to the clash with the 11th (F♯).

C#4 is ambiguous, but most people looking at it would imply it is a C♯sus4 chord spelled C♯, F♯, and G♯. If you even try to look up the C#4 on [jGuitar](http://jguitar.com/chordsearch?chordsearch=C%234&labels=none) all the results show up for C♯sus4 instead of C♯4.

Comment: Nice, concise answer. Definitely a weary issue because of the individual implication by the player.

Answer (score 2):

In Jazz, they usually think the chords in thirds. This means that they will take the root and ascend thirds to find the other notes:

C# (1), E# (maj 3), G# (5), B (b7), D# (9 or D b9), F# (11 -or Fx #11), A# (13).

So, if you have a C#7 chord and want to play F#, you would mark it as C# 11 and not C# 4. Like Dom said, this chord will also have D# in it. If you do not want that, and you simply want to add the F# in a C#7 chord, you can notate it as `C#7 add 4`

Comment: Should that 13th be A#?

Comment: @Tim correct...

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Dom's answer, C#4 SHOULD include C#, E#, G# and F#. Whereas C#sus 4 will only contain C#, F# and G#. That's because the suspension of the 3rd, replaced by the 4th, is why it's a sus. chord. If the composer wants the triad AND the 4th note, it's C#4. As in other answers, by the time we get to numbers larger than 7, we generally inlclude that 7, and the 9, so C#11 will have all those notes as well as the 11th.

There again, if it's C #11, as alluded to by Shev., that's a different one altogether - based on a C chord...Needs to be written out carefully - although context usually gives the relevent clue.